# Как исправить эту ошибку?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, классы, visual-c++, обработка-ошибок

Написал программу для класса "Автобусный билет". Всё работает отлично, но когда в конце программы выводится вместимое файла (метод `set_inf_to_file`), программа останавливается и выскакивает ошибка. Как это исправить?

Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <Windows.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996);
using namespace std;

class bus_ticket
{

public:

    bus_ticket();
    bus_ticket(int, int, int);
    bus_ticket(const bus_ticket&);
    ~bus_ticket();
    void set_inf(int);
    void get_inf();
    void set_inf_to_file(bus_ticket);
    void get_inf_from_file(string);
    int selling();
    void selling(int);
    void selling(bus_ticket);
    string passenger;
    static int get_count();

private:

    time_t current_date_and_time;
    string departure;
    string arrival;
    int ticket_number;
    int seat_number;
    int bus_number;
    bool status = false;
    static int count;

protected:

    char control[100] = { 0 };

};

int bus_ticket::count = 0;

bus_ticket::bus_ticket()
{
    ticket_number = 1000 + rand() % 9000;
    seat_number = 10 + rand() % 40;
    bus_number = 1000 + rand() % 9000;
    current_date_and_time = time(NULL);
    count++;
}

bus_ticket::bus_ticket(int ticket_number_1, int seat_number_1, int bus_number_1)
{
    ticket_number = ticket_number_1;
    seat_number = seat_number_1;
    bus_number = bus_number_1;
    current_date_and_time = time(NULL);
    count++;
}

bus_ticket::bus_ticket(const bus_ticket& other) 
{
    this->ticket_number = other.ticket_number;
    this->bus_number = other.bus_number;
    this->seat_number = other.seat_number;
    this->passenger = other.passenger;
    this->departure = other.departure;
    this->arrival = other.arrival;
    this->current_date_and_time = other.current_date_and_time;
    count++;
}

void bus_ticket::set_inf(int i)
{
    cout << endl << "Enter " << i + 1 << " passenger name: ";
    cin >> passenger;
    cout << "Enter departure: ";
    cin >> departure;
    cout << "Enter arrival: ";
    cin >> arrival;
    cout << endl << endl;
}

void bus_ticket::get_inf()
{
    char buffer[100];
    tm* timeinfo = localtime(&current_date_and_time);
    const char* format = "%A, %B %d, %Y %H:%M:%S";
    strftime(buffer, 100, format, timeinfo);
    cout << "Passenger: " << passenger << endl;
    cout << "Ticket number: " << ticket_number << endl;
    cout << "Date and time of purchase: " << buffer << endl;
    cout << "Seat number: " << seat_number << endl;
    cout << "Bus number: " << bus_number << endl;
    cout << "Departure: " << departure << endl;
    cout << "Arrival: " << arrival << endl;
}

void bus_ticket::set_inf_to_file(bus_ticket ticket)
{
    ofstream fn("text.txt");
    if (!fn.is_open()) 
    {
        cout << "File does not exist!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        fn.write((char*)&ticket, sizeof(bus_ticket));
    }
    fn.close();
    ifstream fn1("text.txt");
    if (!fn1.is_open())
    {
        cout << "File does not exist!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        bus_ticket ticket1;
        cout << "Information about passenger from file: " << endl;
        while (fn1.read((char*)&ticket1, sizeof(bus_ticket)))
        {
            ticket1.get_inf();
        }
    }
    fn1.close();
}

void bus_ticket::get_inf_from_file(string str)
{
    ifstream fn(str);
    if (!fn.is_open())
    {
        cout << "File does not exist!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        string str;
        cout << endl;
        while (!fn.eof()) 
        {
            getline(fn, str);
            cout << str << endl;
        }
    }
    fn.close();
}

int bus_ticket::selling()
{
    return status;
}

void bus_ticket::selling(int i)
{
    set_inf(i);
    get_inf();
    status = true;
}

void bus_ticket::selling(bus_ticket object)
{
    object.get_inf_from_file("text1.txt");
    status = true;
}

int bus_ticket::get_count()
{
    return count;
}

bus_ticket::~bus_ticket()
{
    count--;
}

int main()
{
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    srand(time(NULL));
    int b = 0;
    bus_ticket* object1 = new bus_ticket();
    cout << "For entering info about passenger from keyboard press 1, from file - press 2: ";
    cin >> b;
    switch (b)
    {
    case 1:
        object1->selling(0);
        if (object1->selling())
        {
            cout << "Ticket is sold out!" << endl << endl;
        }
        cout << "Current number of tickets: " << object1->get_count() << endl << endl;
        break;
    case 2:
        object1->selling(*object1);
        if (object1->selling())
        {
            cout << "Ticket is sold out!" << endl << endl;
        }
        cout << "Current number of tickets: " << object1->get_count() << endl << endl;
        break;
    }
    delete object1;
    bus_ticket object2;
    cout << "For entering info about passenger from keyboard press 1, from file - press 2: ";
    cin >> b;
    switch (b)
    {
    case 1:
        object2.selling(1);
        if (object2.selling())
        {
            cout << "Ticket is sold out!" << endl << endl;
        }
        cout << "Current number of tickets: " << object2.get_count() << endl << endl;
        break;
    case 2:
        object2.selling(object2);
        if (object2.selling())
        {
            cout << "Ticket is sold out!" << endl << endl;
        }
        cout << "Current number of tickets: " << object2.get_count() << endl << endl;
        break;
    }
    object2.set_inf_to_file(object2);
    return 0;
}
```

Вот скрин ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка текстом:

> Exception thrown at 0x0095ABF2 in Lab№3.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
> violation writing location 0xDDDDDDDD.

Comment: Скопируйте, пожалуйста, текст ошибки. Нажмите на кнопку "править" под вопросом и вставьте ошибку в виде текста. Спасибо

Comment: А ещё хорошо найти окошко call stack и посмотреть, какая именно строка привела к проблеме

Comment: @KoVadim как это сделать?

Comment: нажать Ctrl+Alt+C (Debug-windows-callstack)

Comment: @KoVadim ошибка в конце деструктора, а именно в закрывающей скобке }, в конце метода set_inf_to_file, а именно в закрывающей скобке }, и  в return 0 в main

Comment: определите operator= для bus_ticket. Правило трех/пяти никто не отменял.

Answer (score 0):

```
void bus_ticket::set_inf_to_file(bus_ticket ticket)
{
    ofstream fn("text.txt");
    if (!fn.is_open()) 
    {
        cout << "File does not exist!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        fn.write((char*)&ticket, sizeof(bus_ticket));
```

Здесь записываете классы `string` из `bus_ticket`.  В этих классах **не** строки, а указатели на выделенную память.

```
    }
    fn.close();
    ifstream fn1("text.txt");
    if (!fn1.is_open())
    {
        cout << "File does not exist!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        bus_ticket ticket1;
        cout << "Information about passenger from file: " << endl;
        while (fn1.read((char*)&ticket1, sizeof(bus_ticket)))
```

Здесь вы загружаете идентичную копию элементов, которую неправильно записали. То-есть `bus_ticket ticket1` - это полная копия `bus_ticket ticket`.

```
        {
            ticket1.get_inf();
        }
```

Здесь вызывается деструктор `bus_ticket ticket1`. И аргумент `bus_ticket ticket` лишается всех своих строк.

```
    }
    fn1.close();
```

Тут вызывается деструктор `bus_ticket ticket`, и он пытается удалить память, которой у него уже нет. Происходит исключение неправильного освобождения памяти.

```
}
```

Записывать в файл нельзя просто `write(..sizeof(структура))`. Нужно писать все три строки в файл индивидуально, их содержимое, а **не** указатели.

Вот пример записи :

```
void bus_ticket::write(ofstream & fn){
  fn << passenger ;
  fn.write((char*)&current_date_and_time,sizeof(current_date_and_time));
  fn << departure ;
  fn << arrival ;
  fn.write((char*)&ticket_number,sizeof(ticket_number));
  fn.write((char*)&seat_number,sizeof(seat_number));
  fn.write((char*)&bus_number,sizeof(bus_number));
  fn.write((char*)&status,sizeof(status));
  fn.write(&(control[0]),sizeof(control));
}
```